# Converting string to long force closes app

Tags: android, string, long-integer

I'm writing an app that need to convert a string entered in a text field to long, but when I run the app, it force closes, what can be wrong?

The app is simple, it just takes the value entered in the text field and, when the user press a button it starts a countdown of this value to 0. (a regressive chronometer)

there is the code:

```
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private boolean timerStarted = false;
private Button buttonStart;
public TextView textView;

private final long interval = 1 * 1000;
long tempTempo2;
long minutos4;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cronometro);

    EditText tempTempo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tempo);
    minutos4 = Long.parseLong(tempTempo.getText().toString());
    tempTempo2 = Long.valueOf(minutos4);


    buttonStart = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimerActivity(minutos4, interval);
    textView.setText(textView.getText() + String.valueOf(minutos4/1000));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well its important for the string to be a long type i.e. not have `"\n" or spaces` in it. Try trimming the string first to get rid of additional characters and then convert to long.